# nginx restrict directory access

Tags: security, nginx

I have a Wordpress site running on nginx. What is the best way to restrict access to **/wp-admin** using nginx?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [the Nginx documentation for the access module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpAccessModule):

```
location /wp-admin {
    allow 192.0.2.0/24;
    deny all;
}
```

That would allow access from `192.0.2.0/24` (which is presumably your administrative network) whilst denying all access from the rest of the Internet.  Obviously adjust the IP range(s) as needed.

If you wanted to do HTTP authentication instead, then you might look at the [documentation for the HTTP basic auth module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpAuthBasicModule).

On the other hand, Wordpress administration is already authentication-protected, so with strong passwords, you shouldn't have a massive amount of trouble.